# What music is playing in episode 95 of Hunter x Hunter?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

I've heard this music playing in a lot of episodes but in episode 95 of Hunter x Hunter it plays at 21:19? what music is this?

Answer (score 1):

The music you are searching for is a part of the HunterxHunter OST , Legend Of the Martial Artist , you can find it [here](https://youtu.be/_T6oBCiIWeY).